# How to access to I2C software with wiringpi library-

Tags: i2c, c, wiringpi

I want to use I2C software instead hardware I2C. Because a buggy parto of the I2C related with clock stretching.

I can enable in boot.txt adding this:

```
dtoverlay=i2c-gpio,bus=3
```

It would create a /dev/i2c-3.

Now I want to access using wiringpi library, but I don't know how to choose bus 3 instead of default bus. 
The wiringpi library saids...

> The ID is the I2C number of the device and you can use the i2cdetect
>   program to find this out. wiringPiI2CSetup() will work out which
>   revision Raspberry Pi you have and open the appropriate device in
>   /dev.

Is there a way to specify which bus do you want to use?

Comment: Looking the code I believe that the answer is easy, I've to use fd = wiringPiI2CSetupInterface ("/dev/i2c-3",  DEV_ADDR) instead of wiringPiI2CSetup ....;

Comment: Welcome.  If you've found a solution that works for you, please consider writing it up as an answer (you may have to wait 24 hrs, unfortunately).

Comment: @goldilocks I don't know if it works... I will have to wait 2 days to check if it works or not...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say in your comment just use the `wiringPiI2CSetupInterface` function.

This function is actually called by `wiringPiI2CSetup`.

E.g. rather than

```c
fd = wiringPiI2CSetup(0x31);
```

Use

```c
fd = wiringPiI2CSetupInterface("/dev/i2c-3", 0x31);
```

Comment: Dude you saved my life :)